# Comparing files based on two columns

Tags: join, awk, merge, grep, compare

I have two files with thousands of lines:

file1:

```
COL22A1 LCT 1 12    0.149667616334  2.16226378401
GPRIN2 TP53 12 170  0.0455368539793 44.2359753827
MUC3A TP53 12 170   0.0455368539793 44.2359753827
```

file2:

```
COL22A1 LCT 12 41 23 0.0296296296296 0.101234567901 0.0567901234568 2.36563
MEGF10 SORCS1 10 21 39 0.0246913580247 0.0518518518519 0.0962962962963 2.30599
```

I want to compare first two columns of these files and if they match I want to print whole line of second file and last column of first file:

output:

```
COL22A1 LCT 12 41 23 0.0296296296296 0.101234567901 0.0567901234568 2.36563 2.16226378401
```

I tried awk, grep, join but it always gives me output of just one file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following and let us know then.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=$NF;next} a[$1,$2]{print $0,a[$1,$2]}' Input_file1  Input_file2
```